# Foundations folder rebuild causing a Mach-O linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I screwed up my app yesterday by deleting the frameworks folder in the left pane of xcode.  Could not reverse this with cmd-z.  After searching here and elsewhere I found a thread that said to check the trash, but it was empty.  So I "discarded changes" which didn't seem to help, as I now had to retrieve 4 files from the trash.  I manually added the frameworks I *think* were there (from HD systems folder), and now I am getting a Apple Mach-O link error:

```
ld: framework not found Cocoa
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

None of the solutions I've found seem to solve the issue.

Also, I'm not sure if this is a second issue or not, but I made a new test app to see what was normally in the frameworks folder, and it doesn't have a frameworks folder at all, and the 2 files in the Products folder are in red text, but the app loads in the simulator.

My last commit was in july - gasp - will going back to that fix the issue?  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Quickest fix is to create a fresh project and just copy your source files. Trust me -- this rabbit hole isn't worth exploring...

Comment: thanks anna, i thought about doing this but danil's answer below is what i ended up doing in the end and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed references to frameworks. Add them in the target's settings: select project name, there select target's name in the left column and "Build Phases" tab in the top.

In the "Link Binary With Libraries" press plus button and add frameworks which you need. I think you need to add UIKit and Foundation to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks, i figured it out already but this answer is absolutely correct